# Ordenar una lista por cierto elemento de la clase C++

Tags: c++, lista, ordenamiento, codeblocks

El proyecto esta en CodeBlocks, lo que quiero es que al momento de mostrar la lista, los muestre ordenados por el campo "Clave" ya sea ascendente o descendente.O que la funcion insertar los ordene y los imprima o viceversa.

#### zapatos.h

```
#ifndef ZAPATOS_H        
#define ZAPATOS_H    
#include<string.h>     
#include<algorithm>    
#include<list>  
#include<iterator>  
#include<iomanip>  
#include<iostream>        
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class zapatos
{
public:
    zapatos();

    void pideDatos();
    void muestraDatos();
    //void eliminarUltimo();
    void eliminar();
    void bubble(zapatos,T n);
    void buscarDato();
    void modificarDato();

    zapatos *siguiente;
    zapatos *anterior;
    zapatos *auxPrimero=NULL;
    zapatos *auxUltimo=NULL;

    int auxZap,auxz2,auxz3;
    zapatos *auxTres;
    zapatos *auxDos;
    zapatos *zapatosLDE;
  private:
    T precio;
    string modelo;
    T clave;

};
template <typename T>
zapatos<T>::zapatos()
{
//ctor
}
template <typename T>
void zapatos<T>::pideDatos(){
zapatosLDE=new zapatos;

cout<< "Ingrese la Clave del producto: ";
cin>>zapatosLDE->clave;
cout<< "Ingrese el Modelo: ";
getline(cin,zapatosLDE->modelo);
getline(cin,zapatosLDE->modelo);
cout<< "Ingrese el precio:$";
cin>>zapatosLDE->precio;
cout<<endl;

zapatosLDE->siguiente=auxPrimero;
    auxPrimero=zapatosLDE;

}/*
template <typename T>
void zapatos<T>::bubble(zapatos clave,T n){
T aux;
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<n-1-i;j++){
        if(zapatosLDE->clave > zapatosLDE->clave[j+1] ){
            aux=clave[j];
            clave[j]=clave[j+1];
            clave[j+1]=aux;
        }
    }
 }
 }
 */
 template <typename T>
 void zapatos<T>::muestraDatos(){

 cout<< "\t|Clave|\t\t|Modelo|\t\t|Precio|"<<endl;
 int clave=0;
 while(zapatosLDE!=NULL){
    //zapatos<T>::bubble(clave ,T n);
    cout<<"\t"<<zapatosLDE->clave<<"\t"
        <<"\t"<<zapatosLDE->modelo<< "\t"
        <<"\t\t$"<<zapatosLDE->precio<<endl;
        zapatosLDE=zapatosLDE->siguiente;
  }

  }/*
  template <typename T>
  void zapatos<T>::sort(){
  int temp_data;
  zapatosLDE=auxPrimero;
  auxTres=zapatosLDE;

  while(zapatosLDE){
    auxTres=zapatosLDE;
    if(zapatosLDE->clave > auxTres->clave){
        temp_data=zapatosLDE->clave;
               zapatosLDE->clave=temp_data;
                auxTres->clave=temp_data;
                break;
    }
  }zapatosLDE=zapatosLDE->siguiente;
  }*/
  template <typename T>
  void zapatos<T>::eliminar(){
   char ask[2];
   int tecla=1;

  zapatosLDE=auxPrimero;

  if(zapatosLDE==NULL){
    cout<< "No hay Datos!"<<endl;
  }else{
    cout<< "Ingrese la clave del producto a eliminar: "<<endl;
    cin>>auxZap;
    do{
        if(auxZap==zapatosLDE->clave){
                cout<< "\nClave: "<<zapatosLDE->clave<<endl
                << "Modelo: "<<zapatosLDE->modelo<<endl
                << "Precio: "<<zapatosLDE->precio<<endl;
        cout<< endl<< "Seguro de continuar? S/N"<<endl;
        cin>>ask[2];
        if((ask[2]=='S')||(ask[2]=='s')){
            auxPrimero=zapatosLDE->siguiente;
            delete(zapatosLDE);
        }
            //zapatosLDE=auxPrimero;
            cout<< "Dato eliminado"<<endl;
            break;
        }else{
            //auxUltimo=zapatosLDE;
            auxTres=zapatosLDE;
                    zapatosLDE=zapatosLDE->siguiente;
            if(zapatosLDE==NULL){
                cout<< "Dat no found"<<endl;
                //break;
            }

        }
            if(auxZap== zapatosLDE->clave){
                    cout<< "\nClave: "<<zapatosLDE->clave<<endl
                << "Modelo: "<<zapatosLDE->modelo<<endl
                << "Precio: "<<zapatosLDE->precio<<endl;
        cout<< endl<< "Seguro de continuar? S/N"<<endl;
        cin>>ask[2];
        if((ask[2]=='S')||(ask[2]=='s')){

            auxDos=zapatosLDE->siguiente;
            delete(zapatosLDE);

            zapatosLDE=auxTres;
            zapatosLDE->siguiente=auxDos;
                        cout<< "Dato elimina2"<<endl;
                        break;
        }
            }
    }while(zapatosLDE!=NULL);
  }
  }

  template <typename T>
  void zapatos<T>::buscarDato(){

  zapatosLDE=auxPrimero;
  if(zapatosLDE==NULL)
    cout<< "Zero elements"<<endl;
   else{
    cout<< "Escriba la clave #:";
    cin>>auxz3;

    int tecla=1;
    do{
        if(auxz3==zapatosLDE->clave){
            cout<< "Clave: "<<zapatosLDE->clave<<endl
                << "Modelo: "<<zapatosLDE->modelo<<endl
                << "Precio:$"<<zapatosLDE->precio<<endl;
            tecla=2;
        }else{
            zapatosLDE=zapatosLDE->siguiente;
            if(zapatosLDE==NULL)
                cout<< "No found!!"<<endl;
        }
     }while((tecla!=2) && (zapatosLDE!=NULL));
   }
  }
  template <typename T>
  void zapatos<T>::modificarDato(){
  int tecla;
  zapatosLDE=auxPrimero;

  if(zapatosLDE==NULL)
    cout<< "No hay elements"<<endl;
  else{
    cout<< "Clave del zapato a modificar: ";
    cin>>auxz2;

    int n=0;
    do{
        if(auxz2==zapatosLDE->clave){
            cout<<endl
                <<"Clave "<<zapatosLDE->clave<<endl
                << "Modelo "<<zapatosLDE->modelo<<endl
                << "Precio "<<zapatosLDE->precio<<endl<<endl;

            cout<< "Qué quiere modificar?: "<<endl
                << "1.clave"<<endl
                << "2.modelo"<<endl
                << "3.precio"<<endl;
            cin>>tecla;

            n=1;
            switch(tecla){
            case 1:
                cout<< "Escriba la nueva clave"<<endl;
                cin>>zapatosLDE->clave;
                break;

            case 2:
                cout<< "Escriba el nuevo modelo"<<endl;
                getline(cin,zapatosLDE->modelo);
                getline(cin,zapatosLDE->modelo);
                break;

            case 3:
                cout<< "Escriba el nuevo precio"<<endl;
                cin>>zapatosLDE->precio;
                break;
            }
        }else{
            zapatosLDE=zapatosLDE->siguiente;
            if(zapatosLDE==NULL)
                cout<< "Dato no encontrado!!"<<endl;
        }
    }while( (zapatosLDE!=NULL) && (n==0));
  }
  }

  #endif // ZAPATOS_H
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>  
#include"zapatos.h"  
#include<string.h>  
#include<cstdlib>  
#include<algorithm>  
#include<conio.h>  
using namespace std;  

int main()  
{
 zapatos<int> Z;

 bool flag=false;
 char tecla;

 do{
    system("cls");
    cin.clear();

    cout<< "\t***Elige una opcion***"<<endl
        << "\t1)Agregar"<<endl
        << "\t2)Quitar"<<endl
        << "\t3)Buscar"<<endl
        << "\t4)Mostrar Lista"<<endl
        << "\t5)Modificar"<<endl
        << "\t6)Salir"<<endl;
    cin>>tecla;

    switch(tecla){
    case '1':
        cout<<endl<< "Opcion 1)Insertar"<<endl;
        Z.pideDatos();
        system("pause");
        break;

    case '2':
        cout<<endl<< "Opcion 2)Eliminar"<<endl;
        Z.eliminar();
        system("pause");
        break;

    case '3':
        cout<<endl<< "Opcion 3)Buscar"<<endl;
        Z.buscarDato();
        system("pause");
        break;

    case '4':
        cout<<endl<< "Opcion 4)Mostar"<<endl;

        Z.muestraDatos();
        system("pause");
        break;

    case '5':
        Z.modificarDato();
        system("pause");
        break;

    case '6':
        cout<< "Hasta Luego :-)";
        flag=true;
        break;
    }
}while(flag!=true);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se qué margen de libertad tienes a la hora de resolver esta práctica, pero lo cierto es que el diseño de `zapatos<T>` es horroroso. Una sola clase es a la vez una lista enlazada y un nodo... además de exponer su lógica interna (los punteros de la lista enlazada) alegremente, lo cual termina por romper cualquier concepto de encapsulamiento.

Otra inconsistencia que existe es que se supone que la lista es doblemente enlazada y sin embargo en la creación de los nodos únicamente se inicializa el puntero `siguiente`, con lo que el doble enlace se pierde irremediablemente.

Dicho esto, ordenar los registros puede ser una operación trivial si utilizas, por ejemplo, un vector. La idea es volcar la lista a un vector, ordenar dicho vector y volver a *coser*  la lista resultante. De esta forma te evitas tener que lidiar la problemática de los punteros al mover nodos de sitio constantemente:

```
std::vector<zapatos<T>*> lista;
zapatos<T>* ptr = siguiente;

// Se vuelca la lista al vector
while( ptr )
{
  lista.push_back(ptr);
  ptr++;
}

// Se ordenan los registros
std::sort(lista.begin(),lista.end(),
          [](zapatos<T>* ptr1, zapatos<T>* ptr2)
          { return ptr1->clave < ptr2->clave; });

// Se recompone la lista
siguiente = lista[0];
ptr = siguiente;

for( size_t i=1; i<lista.size(); ++i )
{
  // Se actualizan los punteros de la lista
  ptr->siguiente = lista[i];
  lista[i]->anterior = ptr;

  ptr = lista[i];    
}
```

Lo ideal sería ubicar esta lógica en una función `ordenar()` o similar ya que no es necesario ejecutarla constantemente.

Otra posibilidad, si la lista ha de estar siempre ordenada en función de la clave, es obligar a que la lista esté siempre ordenada. Esto lo puedes conseguir modificando la función `pideDatos` para que en vez de añadir el elemento al inicio de la lista inserte el elemento en la posición que le corresponda. También habría que modificar la función `modificarDato` para que, en el caso de modificar la clave, se recalcule la nueva posición del elemento.

```
template <typename T>
void zapatos<T>::pideDatos()
{
  zapatosLDE=new zapatos;

  cout<< "Ingrese la Clave del producto: ";
  cin>>zapatosLDE->clave;
  cout<< "Ingrese el Modelo: ";
  getline(cin,zapatosLDE->modelo);
  cout<< "Ingrese el precio:$";
  cin>>zapatosLDE->precio;
  cout<<endl;

  if( !auxPrimero )
    auxPrimero = zapatosLDE;
  else if( auxPrimero->clave > zapatosLDE->clave )
  {
    zapatosLDE->siguiente = auxPrimero;
    auxPrimero->anterior = zapatosLDE;
    auxPrimero = zapatosLDE;
  }
  else
  {
    zapatos<T>* ptr = auxPrimero;

    while( ptr->siguiente )
    {
      if( ptr->siguiente->clave > zapatosLDE->clave )
        break;
    }  

    if( ptr->siguiente )
    {
      zapatosLDE->siguiente = ptr->siguiente;
      ptr->siguiente->anterior = zapatosLDE;
    }

    ptr->siguiente = zapatosLDE;
    zapatosLDE->anterior = ptr;       
  }
}
```

Y faltaría algo similar para `modificarDato`.

**NOTA FINAL**: Sería recomendable que el constructor inicializase los punteros a `NULL` (desde C++11 lo ideal es usar `nullptr`) así como también deberías implementar el destructor para liberar toda la memoria reservada.

Un saludo.